# C preprocessor - token pasting - confusing result. Why is that?

Tags: c, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I thought this program would print the value `-12--2=-10`. When I run it, it prints `0`.

**I cannot figure out why? Any hints?**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define        ALPHA(x,y)        x##2-y 

int main(void) {
    int i = -1;
    int i2 = -2;
    printf("%d", ALPHA(i, i2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint : preprocessing happens before compilation, and variable names are just tokens at this point. The value they get much later at runtime are irrelevant.

Comment: You were thinking of `ALPHA(-1, i2)`.

Comment: Or is it `ALPHA(-i, 12)`? That also produces `-10`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preprocessing phase is done before any compilation and is done on text. It has no notion of variables or types (that is the compile phase), let alone actual values (runtime).

So, what you are doing is:

```
1) ALPHA(i, i2)
2) i##2-i2
3) i2-i2
```

So you end up with `printf("%d", i2-i2)` which prints zero.

Answer (score 6):

The preprocessor will output that as:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) {
    int i = -1;
    int i2 = -2;
    printf("%d", i2-i2);
    return 0;
}
```

So it will print zero

Answer (score 6):

Compilation process is a bit different in C as compared to other programming languages.
In C, **3 phases** are involved in getting an .exe file from .src file.

*xyz.c* ->  **PREPROCESSOR** ->   *tmp.c*(temporary)   ->  **COMPILER** -> *xyz.obj*-> **LINKER** -> *xyz.exe*

Basically, a preprocessor reads your code line by line and if it is a preprocessing statement, then only it performs the preprocessing directive and outputs your code to the Compiler in pure textual form.

In case of your code,preprocessor will send this code to the compiler for compilation :

```
 //includes stdio.h from include folder

    int main(void)
    {
        int i = -1;
        int i2 = -2;
        printf("%d", i2 - i2);
        return 0;
    }
```

So,when the compiler will compile this code,it will give the **result** for print as **0** only.
This is the reason you are getting 0 printed, when you are running the code. 
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

`ALPHA(i, i2)` becomes `i2-i2`

Per a comment above, pre-processing is textual replacement BEFORE compilation happens.

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up the `i` and `1` characters. Try a different text editor font.

`i ## 2` produces `i2` which happens to be valid in your program, with a value of `-2`.

`1 ## 2` is needed to get the expected `12`.

That doesn't account for the negative sign you seem to expect, but I still like this theory.